# How to enforce a formal protocol with C++ templates?

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming, type-constraints

When using the compile-time duck typing inherent with the [template style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586489/c-interface-vs-template), is there any way to enforce the requirement that the template argument implements certain methods with certain signatures?

```
struct ProtocolT {
  void g() const;
  void h();
}

// I want the compiler to check that T conforms to ProtocolT
// that is, T must implement g() and h() rather than just g()
template <typename T>
void f(const T& x) {
  x.g();
}
```

Of course, even without this, there is perfect type safety: if the template argument  `T` does not have a method used in the template function implementation, the compiler will always complain.

But I find it appealing to state clearly that `class T` must have all the methods specified in some `class ProtocolT`. It would allow me to constrain the design earlier in the development process by requiring methods from `T` that I don't yet use in the template function implementation.

Even if I didn't include any unused methods in `ProtocolT`, I still think a verified protocol conformance would help when I need to write a class usable as `T`. (Of course, no one stops me from writing `ProtocolT` for documentation purposes, but then the compiler won't validate that `ProtocolT` includes at least all the required methods.)

Comment: inherit from `ProtocolT` to enforce implementation and then SFINAE out `T`.

Comment: Related to [does-static-polymorphism-make-sense-for-implementing-an-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771210/does-static-polymorphism-make-sense-for-implementing-an-interface)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is known as [*concepts*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints). They are currently a technical specification; GCC has an implementation of concepts lite.

Using concepts would look something like (I'm not too familiar with the syntax, so it would probably be slightly different):

```
template <typename T>
concept bool Protocol = requires(const T a, T b) {
  { a.g() } -> void;
  { b.h() } -> void;
};

void f(const Protocol& x) {
  x.g();
}
```

---

However, if you want a solution you can use *right now*, you can emulate concepts with a variety of techniques.

You could write type-traits to detect if a function does what you want.

You could also use the [detection idiom](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected), which abstracts the previous technique, greatly reducing boilerplate. For your example:

```
template <typename T>
using g_t = decltype(std::declval<const T&>().g());

template <typename T>
using h_t = decltype(std::declval<T&>().h());

template <typename T>
constexpr bool meets_protocol_v = std::experimental::is_detected_exact_v<void, g_t, T>
            && std::experimental::is_detected_exact_v<void, h_t, T>;
```

In using it, you could either be SFINAE friendly and SFINAE off of `meets_protocol_v`, or you could static assert:

```
template <typename T>
void f(const T& x) {
  static_assert(meets_protocol_v<T>, "Doesn't meet protocol");
  x.g();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe inserting corresponding `static_assert`:

```
static_assert
(
    ::std::is_same< void, decltype(::std::declval< T >().h()) >::value
,   "T must implement void h(void)"
);
```

Also note that in your example when T follows `ProtocolT` requirements it still won't work because `f` accepts a `const` reference to T, while `ProtocolT` only says it should have non-const `g()`.